# whenever i do any change in xml file i need to remove pub/static folder then it works

Tags: magento2.3

I am trying to do some change in default.xml but whenever i do any change in xml layout i have to clear cache and remove pub/static folder var/cache folder . is there any way to skip these steps and to  speedup development. I have tried development mode , production mode but i am not getting any solution of this .server is ubuntu local. and magento 2.3 community is there anything i am able to do to speedup the development process .

Comment: You need to flush the cache only after changing any XML file.
`php bin\magento cache:flush`

Comment: the issue is i am trying everything with cache flush nothing happens

Comment: Have you installed grunt? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html#grunt_prereq

Comment: I dont think it is relevant to my question @khushbu

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your XML change doesn't contain any static content related changes like adding/removing CSS or JS file.